# Design question for remote process

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, user-interface

I'm mixed on how I should design my program.  I'll try to be clear, but it's hard to explain!

Basically, I inject a managed C#.NET Dll into a certain process.  Right now, this Dll can load any other Dll dynamically via reflection (if the other Dll implement the IRunnable interface).

What I would like to have is the following:

A Master GUI that injects the Dll into a process.  You can load from this GUI an extension Dll (via reflection) into the process (all this remotely, the GUI MUST NOT be within that said process).  I want the GUI to communicate via WCF or a named pipe.  Also, once the said Dll has been load via reflection, it must create a GUI in the master user interface.

I'm really confused on how to approach this problem.  Any feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT 1:

Sorry for the late reply I was out of town.  I do know how to inject a DLL and starting the CLR into the remote process, that's not a problem.  I'll try to reformulate the problem in better terms:

- A : Host process (injector)
- B : Target process (the one who's gonna get injected)
- C : Dll to be injected
- D : Dll loaded via reflection from C.  Belongs to process B.

Basically, the problem is I would like that once D gets loaded, it creates a GUI window into A.  Then I would like that GUI window to be able to communicate with D.  How is that possible?  Probably I'm looking at the problem the wrong way, but I'm out of idea.

Answer (score 0):

Do you already know how to inject a DLL into another process? This is not completely trivial, and may involve using hooks or modifying the process' memory (of course, both require the appropriate privileges).

Assuming that you do, I would use .NET Remoting or WCF to create a two-way communication channel between the two processes. If you have any more specific questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to inject a dll from one process into another. That sort of thing just won't work (even in native (unmanaged) applications). One application can "instruct" (or ask) another "cooperating" application to load a specific dll, provided that dll is available locally on the machine. So application "A" could send the dll to application "B" and ask "B" to load the dll as well.

The way application "A" communicates with application "B" is not so important. If you use named pipes both application will have to be on the same network. If you want this to work across networks (internet) then any tcp technology can be used. Http might be the better choice so you can go past firewalls and such. So Http REST could be one option whether you use ASP.NET or WCF is your choice.